How to SUM an item created with a small change pre-processor
I'm using zabbix to collect some data.
I have a value I am monitoring (e.g. inc_value). It is an incrementing value, so each time it is checked it should be larger than before.
It is collected using the key
zbx.sts[inc_value]
which runs every minute.
I then apply a pre-processor of simple change to record the amount it has changed in the last minute.
This all works fine.
However, I also want to record the SUM of these values (the changes) over the preceding hour.
Ideally, it also needs to run every 60 seconds to identify when increases and falls occur.
I can see how to get the SUM of the inc_value using a calculated Item, but I need the SUM of the changes, and can't see how to reference that.
I have Zabbix versions 5 and 6 running currently.

OK, so I worked it out. Create a new item and:

Give it a name
Choose type: calculated
create a key (make one up. I used zbx.clc[inc_value_change_sum]
The formula is: sum(zbx.sts[inc_value], 1h)
Fill in the other sections accordingly

I've checked this manually against the live data, and it appears to be coming up with the right amounts.
